# Spring data JPA NPE in validateQuery with custom entityManagerFactory and Query annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm working on a Spring Boot project using spring-boot-starter-parent 1.2.0.RELEASE. I'm attempting configure spring to use Hibernate's JTASssionContext through the spring SpringJtaSessionContext extension.

In my `@Configuration` class I'm returning the JTA configured `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = Event.class)
public class JPAConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean   localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJtaDataSource( dataSource  );
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter( jpaVendorAdapter );
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "jta");
        properties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType", "JTA");
        properties.put( "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" );
        properties.put( "hibernate.format_sql", "true" );
        properties.put( "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringNamingStrategy");
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap( properties );
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

Everything seems to be wired up but I am running into a NPE inside of `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery`

```
/**
 * Validates the given query for syntactical correctness.
 * 
 * @param query
 * @param em
 */
private final void validateQuery(String query, String errorMessage) {

    if (getQueryMethod().isProcedureQuery()) {
        return;
    }

    EntityManager validatingEm = null;

    try {
        validatingEm = getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
 ....
```

The call to `getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();` results in a NPE that seems to be coming out of `createEntityManager()`

The supplied class for `getEntityManager()` seems to be the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` that I defined in JPAConfig. The supplied `EntityManagerFactory` seems to be `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. It seems like something inside of createEntityManager() is null.

This results in the following stacktrace

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.vnomicscorp.dw.model.Event com.vnomicscorp.dw.webservice.repo.EventRepository.findByCompositeKey(com.vnomicscorp.dw.model.Vehicle,com.vnomicscorp.dw.model.EventType,long)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:51)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:202)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:80)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:192)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 240 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.join(CMTTransaction.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:541)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:80)
    ... 253 more
```

The caused by line is pointing at this method reflection invoke

```
    Object retVal = method.invoke(this.nativeEntityManagerFactory, args);
```

I should also add, I am using Spring data rest and have a `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` class as well.

```
@Configuration
public class RestRepoConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Employee.class, Vehicle.class, Customer.class, VehicleMake.class, VehicleModel.class, Event.class);
    }
}
```

The NPE is being thrown while trying to validate a `PagingAndSortingRepository` with added methods.

```
public interface EventRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Event, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM Event AS e WHERE e.vehicle = :vehicle AND e.startTime <= :endTime AND e.endTime >= :startTime")
    public Iterable<Event> findByTimeperiod(@Param("vehicle") Vehicle vehicle,
                                        @Param("startTime") long startTime,
                                        @Param("endTime") long endTime);

    @Query("SELECT e FROM Event AS e WHERE e.vehicle = :vehicle AND e.eventType = :eventType AND e.startTime = :startTime")
    public Event findByCompositeKey(@Param("vehicle") Vehicle vehicle,
                                @Param("eventType") EventType eventType,
                                @Param("startTime") long startTime);
}
```

Comment: Can you share all the code that's necessary to reproduce the problem? What you have above works for me (once I've filled in the blanks).

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I added the PagingAndSortingRepository that seems to be at the root of the NPE.

Comment: Please provide more code of the validateQuery method. I've already got an idea, but.... Also the relevant Stacktrace would greatly help us to check your assumptions against existing information

Comment: I tried with a PagingAndSortingRepository (modifying one of Spring Boot's samples) and it all worked fine. `getEntityManager()` can't return null as there's an assertion that it's non-null. I'm not sure that anything else in that call chain would typically return null, either. You aren't running a test with a mocked `EntityManager` are you? Other than that guess, I think you're going to need to share _all_ of the code that's required to reproduce the problem to make further progress.

Comment: @Vogel612 Added the stacktrace, its really a NPE wrapped up in a RuntimeException.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I added a bit more code after doing some digging, the NPE is coming from inside of createEntityManager() leading me to think its a configuration issue.

Comment: The `JtaPlatform` that Hibernate's configured with is returning `null` from `retrieveTransactionManager`. What JTA provider are you trying to use? You'd probably be better deleting your `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and letting Boot auto-configure it for you using a handful of lines in `application.properties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by Andy Wilkinson is spot on. The problem was a null transaction manager due to a configuration issue.

Comment: Whilst this comment might have solved your problem, it is sidestepping the main issue. the programatic `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` route of configuring persistence is necessary in some cases.